# Linux find command: searching for a filename containing parentheses

Tags: regex, linux, find, parentheses, brackets

I need to find files with filenames like this:

```
<some regex-matched text> (1).<some regex-matched text>
```

i.e. I want to search for filenames containing

- text ending in a space
- then an opening bracket (parenthesis)
- followed by the numeral 1
- followed by a closing bracket
- possibly followed by a dot followed by some more text...

I first went  `find . -regex '.* \(1\)\..*'`. But the brackets are sort of ignored: files matching `.* 1\..*` are returned.

In the course of my attempt to find an answer I found [this page](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html#Regular-Expressions) covering Linux `find`. Here I find this phrase:

> "Grouping is performed with backslashes followed by parentheses ‘\(’,
>   ‘\)’."

*[NB to show you the reader a single backslash, as shown in that page, I have doubled the backslashes to write the single backslashes above!]*

I wasn't sure what to make of that, i.e. how to escape ordinary brackets in that case. I thought maybe doubling up the backslashes in the `find` expression might work, but it didn't.

Even if I try to do it without using a regex, `find` seems to have some problems with brackets and/or a dot in this place:

```
mike@M17A .../accounts $  find . -name *(1).pdf
[... finds stuff OK]
mike@M17A .../accounts $  find . -name *(1).*
find: paths must precede expression: ..
Usage: find [-H] [-L] [-P] [-Olevel] [-D help|tree|search|stat|rates|opt|exec|time] [path...] [expression]
mike@M17A .../accounts $  find . -name *(1)\.*
find: paths must precede expression: ..
Usage: find [-H] [-L] [-P] [-Olevel] [-D help|tree|search|stat|rates|opt|exec|time] [path...] [expression]
```

NB putting a space after in the initial * in these attempts also fails...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you don't need to escape *these* parenthesis. This should work :

```
find . -regex '.* (1)\(\..*\)?'
```

Though a capture group is used (escaped parenthesis) `\(\..*\)` so that we can make the last match optional (*possibly followed by a dot followed by some more text*) with `?`

Comment: Thanks. I could have sworn I did actually try at some point with unescaped brackets... but obviously not: this works fine.